# How to kill a running task in celery?

Tags: python, task, celery

I am using Celery in python. I have the following task:

```
@app.task
def data():
    while 1:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=300).json()
        db.colloectionName.insert_many(response)
        sleep(10000)
```

This task gets data from a web server and saves it on MongoDB in a loop.
I have called it by the following code:

```
data.delay()
```

it works fine. But, I want to kill it by programming. I tried by `data.AsyncResult(task_id).revoke()`
but it does not work.
How can I kill a running task in celery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you doing data.AsyncResult? You can try doing something like this.

```
from celery.task.control import revoke
revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Also, further details can be found here:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks

Comment: Thank you. it worked fine. But, the problem is when I call a task by `data.delay()` it gives different task_id in every time. How can I get running task_id?

Comment: Also, there is no point having a celery task with a infinite while loop inside. You can instead have a celery beat schedule triggering the task every time you wish to. Cleaner and a lot easier to handle.

Comment: Also, accept the answer if it works so that others can find with ease.

Comment: Can you give an example in my case to use celery beat?

Comment: It is fairly easy to implement, you can look for any online blog. https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
res = data.delay()
res.revoke()
```

but I don't understand the point of using Celery in your scenario. How does Celery help you if you're doing a `while 1` loop?

Consider breaking it down to a small task that performs a single HTTP request and add Celery beat to call it every 10 seconds.
You can stop beats whenever you like.

Comment: Can you give an example in my case to use celery beat?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html this example shows how to run in 10 seconds interval. Note that beat run on a different process (in addition to the worker process)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
revoke(task_Id, terminate=True)
```